# How to add category id to another table on selection of category?

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables ( post , category )

```sql
CREATE TABLE post    
(pid INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,    
post_title VARCHAR(255),   
post_result VARCHAR(255),  
post_content VARCHAR(500), 
cid INT(10), 
PRIMARY KEY (pid),
FOREIGN KEY (cid) REFERENCES category(cid));   

CREATE TABLE category (  
cid INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
cname VARCHAR(50),  
PRIMARY KEY (cid));
```

This is my insert statement:

```
$id = isset($_POST['pid'])?$_POST['pid']:'';
$title=$_POST['post_title'];
$result=$_POST['post_result'];
$content=$_POST['post_content'];
$catid=$_POST['cid'];
$cat=$_POST['cname'];
$insertquery="INSERT INTO review (pid,post_title,post_result,post_content)
VALUES('','$title','$result','$content')";
```

Problem what im facing is, in my post table, the values of category id ( cid ) are NULL for every record.
How do make it to store the value of selected category.

This is my form:

```
<form id="create" action="insert.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="post_title" placeholder="Title" /><br> 
<input type="text" name="post_result" placeholder="Final comment" /><br>
<textarea name="post_content" placeholder="Review" ></textarea><br>

    Category:
    <select name=cname>
    <option value="select"></option>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    <option value="4">Option 4</option>
    <option value="5">Option 5</option>
        </select><br><br>

<input class="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>

</form>
```

Do help in getting the output .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First of all** I hope that you populate your category select from db and `value` attribute contains category id. That being said it's better to change `name` attribute to `cid` (because that what you expect in POST):

```
<select name="cid">
```

Then `var_dump($_POST)` will look like this:

```
array(5) {
  ["post_title"]=>
  string(2) "aa"
  ["post_result"]=>
  string(2) "bb"
  ["post_content"]=>
  string(2) "cc"
  ["cid"]=>
  string(1) "2"
  ["submit"]=>
  string(6) "Submit"
}
```

**Secondly** you can ditch following php lines:

```
$id = isset($_POST['pid'])?$_POST['pid']:'';
$cat=$_POST['cname'];
```

because you don't send those values with the form and don't use them.

**Thirdly** you need to correct your insert statement

```
$insertquery="INSERT INTO post (post_title,post_result,post_content,cid)
              VALUES('$title','$result','$content','$catid')";
```

Other considerations:

- You better ensure on the client side that category name has been chosen, otherwise you'll get error trying to insert the record in `post`.
- As a1ex07 mentioned you need to check and sanitize all user input before you put in db
- Switch to prepared statements

Comment: Thanks alot Sir . It's working . Had been struggling with this past 2 days .

Answer (score 0):

Assuming category name is unique, you can do

```
$insertquery="INSERT INTO review (pid,post_title,post_result,post_content,cid)
VALUES('','$title','$result','$content', 
 (SELECT cid FROM category WHERE cname ='$cname'))"
```

You also need to escape all variables that come from user (preferable way is to use pdo or mysqli).

Answer (score 0):

In your `INSERT` query, you forgot to add the value of `cname`:

```
$insertquery="INSERT INTO review (pid,post_title,post_result,post_content,cid)
VALUES('','$title','$result','$content',$cname)";
```